# page cannot display error on client system

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer, iis-7, windows-server-2008

I'm using windows server 2008 & IIS 7.0 to deploy the my vb.net 3.5 application.
I'm successfully able to run the URL on my server.
Same URL having IP address & port number configured is not working  on client system.

It is showing IE default error message as "page cannot display"

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things to do:

- Try it in something other than IE - Or at the very least turn off IE "Friendly http error messages" as they obscure the real problem (Tools -> Internet Options -> Advanced)
- Make sure the IIS website is bound to all IP Addresses not just 127.0.0.1 (localhost)
- Make sure the windows firewall / other firewalls in use are configured to allow incoming traffic on port 80 through (assuming you're using port 80)
- Check the event logs - If it's a coding problem, the error message is usually dumped in there
- If the client system is on a different network, make sure that all your firewalls/routers are set up to allow the appropriate traffic through

Some more information which would help us:

- Where (in network terms) is the client you mention? same network?
- What happen if you use the full URL the client's using from a browser on the server?
- When you say it works on your server, is that the VS development server? or the same server the client is using?

Comment: Great reply, thanks, my server's firewall setting was blocked for outside connection. after allowing to my application having port 88, it started working.